# Why does not localStorage save the last symbol in this component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

In the code below, when I change the text of input the localStorage does not save the last symbol. As if I write qwerty, refresh and it gives only qwert.

```
let NameAndCity = React.createClass ({
getInitialState: function() {
return {
  name: this.props.name,
  city: this.props.city
};
},

componentWillMount: function() {
let username = localStorage.getItem('username')
let city = localStorage.getItem('city')
if(username && city){
  this.setState({
    name: username,
    city: city
  })
} else {localStorage.setItem('username', this.state.name)
localStorage.setItem('city', this.state.city)}
},

changeName(e){
this.setState({name: e.target.value})
localStorage.setItem('username', this.state.name)
},

changeCity(e){
this.setState({city: e.target.value})
localStorage.setItem('city', this.state.city)
},

render(){return (
<div className='name-and-city'>
  <input value={this.state.name} onChange={(e)=> this.changeName(e)}/>
  <input value={this.state.city} onChange={(e)=> this.changeCity(e)}/>
</div>
)}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. You are updating the `state` with `onChange` event. But you are using the `this.state.name` without setting the state. Since `setState` is `async` try to use the `state` value in a `callback` as follows.

```
changeName(e){
   var _this = this;
   this.setState({name: e.target.value}, function(){
       localStorage.setItem('username', _this.state.name);
   });
},
```

**or**

Simply use the `event.target.value` to store in `localStoarge`

```
changeCity(e){
    this.setState({city: e.target.value}); //here state.name != e.target.value
    localStorage.setItem('city', e.target.value);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` does not automatically update the state object in React. You can use the `target.value` when you store in localStorage.

```
changeName(e){
  this.setState({name: e.target.value})
  localStorage.setItem('username', e.target.value)
},
```

check the [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more info

Answer (score 0):

See [React.js docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

To fix this, you can pass a callback to `setState` or use `componentDidUpdate`:

```js
this.setState({ name: e.target.value }, () => {
  localStorage.setItem('username', this.state.name)
})
```